# Replace Upper case letters with Lower case - and vice versa

Tags: c#, string

Input String : "This is a String"
Output " tTHIS IS A sTRING

I'm able to convert the upper case to lower case but somehow I'm not able to link them :(.

here is my code.. could someone please help me out here ?

```
static void Main()
{
    string lstr = "";
    string ustr = "";
    Console.WriteLine("Enter the string");
    string str = Console.ReadLine();

    char[] strchararr = str.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < strchararr.Length; i++)
    {

        if (strchararr[i]>='a'&& strchararr[i]<='z')
        {
            ustr += char.ToUpper(strchararr[i]);

        }

        else if (strchararr[i] >= 'A' && strchararr[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            lstr+=char.ToLower(strchararr[i]);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: What do you mean `but somehow I'm not able to link them`

Comment: check if `Char.IsUpper` or `Char.IsLower` and then use `Char.ToUpper()` or `Char.ToLower()`

Answer (score 5):

Use linq

```
var converted = str.Select(x => char.IsUpper(x) ? char.ToLower(x) : char.ToUpper(x));
var result = new string(converted.ToArray);
```

Or a `foreach` approach

```
foreach (var c in str)
   if (char.IsUpper(c))
      result += char.ToLower(c);
   else 
      result += char.ToUpper(c);
```

or

```
foreach (var c in str)
    result += char.IsUpper(c) ? char.ToLower(c) : char.ToUpper(c);
```

or a `for` loop

```
for (int i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
   if (char.IsUpper(str[i]))
      result += char.ToLower(str[i]);
   else 
      result += char.ToUpper(str[i]);
```

or

```
for (var i = 0; i < str.Length; i++)
     result += char.IsUpper(str[i]) ? char.ToLower(str[i]) : char.ToUpper(str[i]);
```

Or a ridiculously stupid (yet super efficient) `unsafe` pointer version (ASCII only)

```
fixed (char* cStr = str)
   for (var c = cStr; c < cStr + str.Length; c++)
     *c = (char)(*c >= 'A' && *c <= 'Z' ? *c + 32 : *c >= 'a' && *c <= 'z' ? *c - 32 : *c);
```

Comment: `result +=` - are you really appending characters to string in a loop?

Comment: @AntonínLejsek nope, *looks around nervously*

Answer (score 1):

Your code has a few problems.

You are using two strings `ustr` and `lstr`. You should instead use one single string to store the result, and append the result of `char.ToLower` and `char.ToUpper` to that string.

You are also not handling anything else other than A-Z and a-z. You should add an `else` block to just append whatever the character is (no conversion needed).

```
    char[] strchararr = str.ToCharArray();

    for (int i = 0; i < strchararr.Length; i++)
    {

        if (strchararr[i]>='a'&& strchararr[i]<='z')
        {
            finalString += char.ToUpper(strchararr[i]);

        }

        else if (strchararr[i] >= 'A' && strchararr[i] <= 'Z')
        {
            finalString+=char.ToLower(strchararr[i]);
        } else {
            finalString += strchararr[i];
        }
    }

    Console.WriteLine(finalString);
```

If you want to handle letters from other alphabets (e.g. Cyrillic, Greek), you should use [`char.IsLower`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.islower?view=netframework-4.7.2) and [`char.IsUpper`](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/system.char.isupper?view=netframework-4.7.2) to check for case.

Comment: Thank you so much for your help and explanation. It completely make sense..

Comment: @Ash0214 Please considering accepting the answer that you think is the best by clicking on that checkmark!

Answer (score 0):

By "link them" I suppose you mean how do you get a whole resulting string?
In that case, no need to use both lstr and ustr variables, use just one.

For example:
replace the line

```
        ustr += char.ToUpper(strchararr[i]);
```

with

```
        lstr += char.ToUpper(strchararr[i]);
```

Answer (score 0):

With char as numbers:
applicable when all the characters have `CodePoints` below `256`.

```
StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder(input.Length);
foreach (char c in input)
    sb.Append(!char.IsLetter(c) ? c : c < 97 ? (char)(c + 32) : (char)(c - 32));
```